# Issue on running first example in caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, lmdb

I am a beginner in Caffe and Python.
I installed Caffe and compiled it successfully in ubuntu 16.04. I created an environment in anaconda 2 and used Cmake for compiling. 
I ran this code and it printed caffe version.

```
$ python -c "import caffe;print caffe.__version__"
1.0.0-rc3
```

So I suppose that I have installed correctly.
I wanted to have my first experience in caffe, so I followed the instructions in [this link](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/). But I am not really familiar with this. It is giving me this error:

```
~/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/code$ python create_lmdb.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_lmdb.py", line 21, in <module>
    import lmdb
ImportError: No module named lmdb
```

I really appreciate if someone can guide me how to start running examples and models in caffe.

Comment: have you installed all pre-requisites?

Comment: Thanks Shai I followed the instructions from this website (https://yangcha.github.io/Caffe-Conda/). I hope I have installed all pre-requisites.

Comment: It seems like the instructions include installation of lmdb library, but not the python interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to install LMDB python package:
https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/

Comment: Thanks Shai for your help and reply. I installed LMDB and now it is giving new error                                                                                       '~/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/code$ python create_lmdb.py
Creating train_lmdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_lmdb.py", line 64, in <module>
    in_db = lmdb.open(train_lmdb, map_size=int(1e12))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/input/train_lmdb'

Comment: @S.EB please do not post code in comments: its incomprehensible.

Comment: so sorry for that

Comment: please check that the path `/home/ubuntu/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/input/` exists. if not, try creating the directory.

Comment: I checked the input folder with pwd and the path is this `/home/smy/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/input` . I really do not know what to do. Stupid mistakes.... :(

Comment: Thank you so much Shai, I could solve this issue. I edited the path in the python file.